# mysql JSON найти по элементу в массиве

Tags: php, mysql, json

разбираюсь сейчас с одной задачей, нужно найти GUID по номеру телефона, который в массиве в объекте JSON, и впринципе как-бы он находит... но мне не очень то и нравится.

Есть JSON массив `phones` в таблице `phonebook`

```
[{"phone": "8800***3535", "comment": "Какой-то комментарий"}, {"phone": "895***59900", "comment": "Какой-то комментарий"}]
```

и в этой же строке есть поле `guid`

Нужно вывести GUID который принадлежит. Но нужно по любому из элементов массива, грубо говоря найти "чёрт побери" кому номер относится

Вот такой код у меня работает, но я понимаю что он не правильный,

```
SELECT guid FROM phonebook WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(phonebook.phones, '{"phone":"8800***3535"}')
```

кто мастера JSON подскажите!)

Первый пост... вроде как опыт есть, но видимо его нет

Comment: Создайте модельный fiddle со структурой и примером данных и дайте ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать функцию `JSON_SEARCH` *([wiki](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search))*. Эта функция доступна с `MySQL 5.7`

Вот решение:

```
SELECT `guid` FROM `phonebook` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(`phones`, 'one', '8800***3535', NULL, '$[*].phone') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Да! Отлично! всё прекрасно

Answer (score 0):

Костыль, конечно, но всё же.

```
SELECT `guid` FROM `phonebook` WHERE `phones` LIKE '%"8800***3535"%'
```

В выражении `%"8800***3535"%` процент будет означать любое количество (включая 0) любых символов. В представленном конкретном случае поиск строки будет происходить по правилам:

- Любые символы до необходимого выражения
- Необходимое выражение – `"8800***3535"`
- Любые символы после необходимого выражения

Если проще говоря, данный способ не будет декодировать JSON и выбирать конкретный параметр, а просто будет сравнивать строку с шаблоном: `любые символы + кавычка + необходимый номер + кавычка + любые символы`.

Можно немного отредактировать, чтоб искался шаблон `"phone": "8800***3535"`.

```
SELECT `guid` FROM `phonebook` WHERE `phones` LIKE '%"phone": "8800***3535"%'
```